# How do I recurrently process irregular lists until they are empty?

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to solve the following task:
I have two sorted lists A and B. Let's say

`A={0, 1, 8, 10, 16, 17, 24, 32, 33, 34, 40, 48}` and

`B={1, 2, 3, 9, 17, 18, 25, 27, 33, 34, 41}`.

From those two lists I want to create pairs s.t. an element b from list B is paired with the biggest element a from A that is smaller than or equal to b. But also every element should go into maximum one pair. Also we only look ahead. That is, if we have put the nth element of A into a pair already, the next element from b we only compare to elements n+1, n+2, and so on from list A. That means some elements will be "lost" throughout the process. This is not a problem. To give an example, the result set of pairs P for the above lists would be as follows:

```
P={{1,1},{8,9},{17,17},{24,25},{33,33},{34,34},{40,41}}
```

Note that the pairs do not **have** to be sorted but in this example they are always of the form `{A[x],B[y]}`

To give an idea of how one would construct P by hand we go through the first few steps:

1. Take first element of B: B[1]=1
2. Compare B[1]to the first element of A -> 1>=0. This means A[1] = 0 is a possible candidate for the first pair
3. Compare B[1] to A[2] -> 1>=1. This means A[2] is a possible candidate for the first pair
4. Compare B[1] to A[3] -> 1<8. This means A[2] is the value for the first pair
5. First Pair is {A[2],B[1]} = {1,1}
6. Look for the next pair on the lists A'={8, 10, 16, 17, 24, 32, 33, 34, 40, 48} and B'={ 2, 3, 9, 17, 18, 25, 27, 33, 34, 41}

The next value in B' would be 2 but no value in A' is smaller than or equal to 2 so we go on to the next one in B' which is 3. Still we only have bigger values in A'. The next pair we get is then {A'[1],B'[3]}={8,9} and so on.

The problem is not really intuitive I think and I have tried alot but cannot seem to get this to work right in mathematica.

Things I have tried include doing it recursively like one would in a standard programming language and using loops. But I run into recursion depth exceptions and other problems. I would rather do it 'right' or in some nice way. Maybe some List Mapping is possible here?

I appreciate every help

Comment: Hello, Can you clarify: `P={{1,1},{8,9},{17,17},{24,25},{33,33},{34,34},{41,40}}`  Are these unordered pairs?  It looks like `{8,9}` is `{A[[3]],B[[4]]}`  but  `{41,40}` is `{B[[-1]],A[[-2]]}`

Comment: Oh, thanks for catching that, it mustve slipped past me. Yes, they are unordered because the main goal is to calculate the mean of the two values. But it would be nice to have the pairs by themselves as well. In a question like this though, i guess it would make sense to create the pairs uniformly that is they should always be of the form {A[x], B[y]}. I will go ahead and correct it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this on a couple of use cases.

```
A = {0, 1, 8, 10, 16, 17, 24, 32, 33, 34, 40, 48};
B = {1, 2, 3, 9, 17, 18, 25, 27, 33, 34, 41};
Module[{aA = Reverse@A, res},
 Table[
  If[bs >= aA[[-1]],
   {aA, res} = TakeDrop[aA, -1 + First@FirstPosition[aA, a_ /; a <= bs]];
   {res[[1]], bs},
   Nothing
   ],
  {bs, B}]
 ]

(* {{1, 1}, {8, 9}, {17, 17}, {24, 25}, {33, 33}, {34, 34}, {40, 41}} *)
```

Comment: I suspect this method does way too much list-processing and hence will be slow,

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear[f]
A = {0, 1, 8, 10, 16, 17, 24, 32, 33, 34, 40, 48};
B = {1, 2, 3, 9, 17, 18, 25, 27, 33, 34, 41};
f[A_, B_] := 
 Module[{ia = 1, ib = 1}, 
  Reap[While[ib <= Length@B, 
     If[A[[ia]] <= B[[ib]], 
      While[ia <= Length@A && A[[ia]] <= B[[ib]], ++ia]; 
      Sow@{A[[ia - 1]], B[[ib]]}; 
      If[ia > Length@A, Break[]]]; ++ib]][[2, 1]]]
f[A, B]
```

> {{1, 1}, {8, 9}, {17, 17}, {24, 25}, {33, 33}, {34, 34}, {40, 41}}

```
SeedRandom[123];
A = Sort@RandomInteger[10^7, 10^5];
B = Sort@RandomInteger[10^7, 10^5];
f[A, B]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.364366, Null}

Answer (score 3):

According to the given conditions, we can combine `Do` and `While` to get the pairs and at the end split the list of pairs according to the first element of each pair using `SplitBy`, and finally take the first elements of the resulting sublists and thus obtain the desired output:

```
A = {0, 1, 8, 10, 16, 17, 24, 32, 33, 34, 40, 48};
B = {1, 2, 3, 9, 17, 18, 25, 27, 33, 34, 41};

createPairs[A_List, B_List] := Module[{pairs, ia},
    pairs = {};
    ia = 1;
    Do[
        While[And[LessEqual[ia, Length @A], LessEqual[A[[ia]], b]],
            Increment @ ia
        ];
        If[Greater[ia, 1],
            AppendTo[pairs, {Part[A, ia - 1], b}]
            ],
            {b, B}
        ];
    Map[First, SplitBy[pairs, First]]
   ];

createPairs[A, B]
```

Result:

> `{{1, 1}, {8, 9}, {17, 17}, {24, 25}, {33, 33}, {34, 34}, {40, 41}}`